# Custom Iterable type

Tags: typescript

I basically want a type which says, you need to implement symbol.iterator, and the rest of the object can or can not be some amount of string: value entries.

I tried to do something like this

```js
interface MyIterable<T> {
    [index: string]: T
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>;
}
```

My thought was, this would create a 'type' which would allow me to to something like this:

```js
const test: MyIterable<number> = {
  'string': 1,
  'string2': 2,
  // and more 'string': number entries
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* (): Iterator<number> {
    for (const key of Object.keys(this)) {
      yield this[key]
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work. Having `[index: string]` and `[Symbol.iterator]()` at the same time, doesn't work.
How would I achieve something like this? Maybe I miss some basic understanding here.

Comment: `const test: MyIterable<number> & {[k: string]: number}`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I tried `type MyIterable<T> = {[index: string]: T} & Iterable<T>` and `const test: {[index: string]: T} & Iterable<T>` directly.